# Why does my Acivity restart after the SurfaceView gets destroyed?

Tags: android, android-activity, surfaceview

I use a `SurfaceView` that implements `SurfaceHolder.Callback` and use `setContentView()` in my main `Activity`.

Now, the `SurfaceView` gets destroyed after I turn off my screen or exit out of the application, but when I turn the screen back on and unlock the phone, or re-open the application, my `Activity` restarts completely, setting the content view to a new instance of my `SurfaceView`.

I'm using the `SurfaceView` to draw my game, and I don't like it that my game has to restart completely after just turning off the screen and turning it back on, or after re-opening the application. I would much rather have my game pick up where it left off.

Is there a better game loop structure that will allow my game to pick up where it left off rather than have to restart? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Are you using onResume() method for setting up surfaceview and other stuff ?

Comment: Your onResume() will called, when you are again back to your app.

Comment: Okey! Implement it and let me know what will be the result.

Comment: Take a look at the structure of Android Breakout (https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/) for an example of how to pause and resume cleanly.  (It uses GLSurfaceView, but that's not too different.)